# Android Studio - App has stopped after upgrade to android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

I tried to make an app when I use android version 2.3.3. However, when I migrate to version 3.0, my application becomes "has stopped" in the emulator. How to solve this problem?
I have updated sdk and gradle. I have made sure no updates are left that I have not done yet.
Here is the error from logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.martin.app.donorkuyadmin, PID: 3870
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.martin.app.donorkuyadmin/com.martin.app.donorkuyadmin.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.dd.CircularProgressButton
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.dd.CircularProgressButton
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.dd.CircularProgressButton
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
                                                                            at com.martin.app.donorkuyadmin.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:30)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 12 to dimension: type=0x3
                                                                            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimension(TypedArray.java:621)
                                                                            at com.dd.CircularProgressButton.initAttributes(CircularProgressButton.java:196)
                                                                            at com.dd.CircularProgressButton.init(CircularProgressButton.java:84)
                                                                            at com.dd.CircularProgressButton.<init>(CircularProgressButton.java:73)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414) 
                                                                            at com.martin.app.donorkuyadmin.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:30) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Your problem is in the log: _"Can't convert value at index 12 to dimension"_  You have a value that cannot be converted into a dimension unit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a same issue, looks like something is wrong when using dependence in gradle for this library in android studio 3.0, below steps worked for me.

1. Remove dependence **compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'** from gradle.
2. Download the library and add it as project module. https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button

Steps to Import Module in Android Studio.

1. Go to File -> New -> Import Module...
2. Select the source directory of the Module you want to import and click Finish.
3. Open Project Structure and open Module Settings for your project.
4. Open the Dependencies tab.
5. Click the (+) icon and select Module Dependency. Select the module and click Ok.
6. Open your build.gradle file and check that the module is now listed under dependencies.

Comment: I have done it. And now where I have to put the dependency so I can use CircularProgressButton.

Comment: Oh I see ... I have imported Circular Progress Button from the library that has been added. Then I try build => clean project. And it works. Thank you so much: D: D

Comment: Hey there, I have imported the library directory from github, added as a dependency but on building I get errors with versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE) and proguard

Comment: @Burf2000 Add VERSION_CODE=1 in root/gradle.properties or you can simple write versionCode 1 in your app gradle file. For proguard issue change  runProguard false with  minifyEnabled false in module/build.gradle.

Comment: are you gonna import the entire folde ? circular-progress-button-master or just the library inside ?

Comment: Just import the inside library